How to create unaggregated variables in grouped polars dataframe
import polars as pl

df_a = pl.DataFrame({'recipe': 'A','values': [1,2,3]})
df_b = pl.DataFrame({'recipe': 'B','values': [1,2,3]})

df = pl.concat([df_a, df_b], rechunk=True)

I would like to compute cumsums by group, but .with_columns does not apply to grouped data ...
df.group_by('recipe').with_columns(cum_val = np.cumsum(pl.col('values')))

In R I could perform this operation as
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> group_by(cyl) |> mutate(cum_wt=cumsum(wt))


In polars you can use window functions directly. Try:
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("values")
    .cum_sum()
    .over("recipe")
)

Which results in:
recipe,values
A,1
A,3
A,6
B,1
B,3
B,6

